# Ubuntu boot error

Tags: boot, kernel

Ubuntu 11.04

After failed try of installing Windows on same machine, Ubuntu doesn't boot. GRUB starts well, but when I try to choose Ubuntu only "Killed" message appears on the top left corner .

If I try to boot using live cd, after I choose "Boot without install" something like "Kernel panic" message appears and so I can only reboot.

Samsung R525

Answer (score 0):

Kernel panic usually happens if you have a hardware fault. Check your hardware foe defects.